# tile3 + struts says no definiton found in Jetty

Tags: struts2, jetty, tiles-3

I tried tiles3+struts/spring mvc several days with jetty9, it doesn't work at all reporting **no definition error**. I checked the configuration again and again. At last I switched to **tomcat for luck with the same war**, and I am! Tiles2 works in jetty9.  Here is the detail:

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0" metadata-complete="true">

    <display-name>XX</display-name>


    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.tiles.extras.complete.CompleteAutoloadTilesListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>100000</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file></welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
    <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
        <result-types>
            <result-type name="tiles"
                         class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
        </result-types>
        <action name="*Page" method="{1}" class="com.homhon.web.booking.TilesAction">
            <result name="home" type="tiles">home</result>
            <result name="aboutUs" type="tiles">aboutUs</result>
            <result name="contactUs" type="tiles">contactUs</result>
            <result name="registration" type="tiles">registration</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

tiles.xml file is in /WEB-INF directly, tiles3 should find all files in this folder with pattern WEB-INF/**/tiles*.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN"
        "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">

<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="baseLayout" template="/WEB-INF/layouts/baseLayout.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Template" />
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/templates/header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="menu" value="/WEB-INF/templates/menu.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/templates/body.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/templates/footer.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="home" extends="baseLayout">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Home Page" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/pages/home.jsp" />
    </definition>
    <definition name="aboutUs" extends="baseLayout">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="About Us Page" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/pages/aboutUs.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="contactUs" extends="baseLayout">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Contact Us Page" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/pages/contactUs.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="registration" extends="baseLayout">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Register Here" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/pages/registration.jsp" />
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

logs shows:

```
2094 [main] DEBUG o.apache.commons.digester.Digester - register('-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN', 'jar:file:/XXX/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-web.war-_web-any-/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/tiles-core-3.0.0.jar!/org/apache/tiles/resources/tiles-config_3_0.dtd'
2094 [main] DEBUG o.apache.commons.digester.Digester - register('-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.0//EN', 'jar:file:/XXX/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-web.war-_web-any-/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/tiles-compat-3.0.0.jar!/org/apache/tiles/compat/resources/tiles-config_2_0.dtd'
2094 [main] DEBUG o.apache.commons.digester.Digester - register('-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.1//EN', 'jar:file:/XXX/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-web.war-_web-any-/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/tiles-compat-3.0.0.jar!/org/apache/tiles/compat/resources/tiles-config_2_1.dtd'
2094 [main] DEBUG o.apache.commons.digester.Digester - register('-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 1.1//EN', 'jar:file:/XXX/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-web.war-_web-any-/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/tiles-compat-3.0.0.jar!/org/apache/tiles/compat/resources/tiles-config_1_1.dtd'
2094 [main] DEBUG o.apache.commons.digester.Digester - register('-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 1.3//EN', 'jar:file:/XXX/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-web.war-_web-any-/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/tiles-compat-3.0.0.jar!/org/apache/tiles/compat/resources/tiles-config_1_3.dtd'
2094 [main] DEBUG o.apache.commons.digester.Digester - register('-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 1.4//EN', 'jar:file:/XXX/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-web.war-_web-any-/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/tiles-compat-3.0.0.jar!/org/apache/tiles/compat/resources/tiles-config_1_4.dtd'
2125 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.i.s.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver - Resolved location pattern [/WEB-INF/**/tiles*.xml] to resources [ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/tiles.xml]]

org.apache.tiles.definition.NoSuchDefinitionException: Cannot find definition named 'home'
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.mgmt.CachingTilesContainer.render(CachingTilesContainer.java:123) ~[tiles-core-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult.doExecute(TilesResult.java:71) ~[struts2-tiles3-plugin-2.3.12.jar:2.3.12]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:186) ~[struts2-core-2.3.12.jar:2.3.12]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:371) ~[xwork-core-2.3.12.jar:2.3.12]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:275) ~[xwork-core-2.3.12.jar:2.3.12]
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256) ~[struts2-core-2.3.12.jar:2.3.12]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) ~[xwork-core-2.3.12.jar:2.3.12]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176) ~[xwork-core-2.3.12.jar:2.3.12]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) ~[xwork-core-2.3.12.jar:2.3.12]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) ~[xwork-core-2.3.12.jar:2.3.12]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265) ~[xwork-core-2.3.12.jar:2.3.12]
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68) ~[struts2-core-2.3.12.jar:2.3.12]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) ~[xwork-core-2.3.12.jar:2.3.12]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) ~[xwork-core-2.3.12.jar:2.3.12]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138) ~[xwork-core-2.3.12.jar:2.3.12]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) ~[xwork-core-2.3.12.jar:2.3.12]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:249) ~[xwork-core-2.3.12.jar:2.3.12]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) ~[xwork-core-2.3.12.jar:2.3.12]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) ~[xwork-core-2.3.12.jar:2.3.12]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:249) ~[xwork-core-2.3.12.jar:2.3.12]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) ~[xwork-core-2.3.12.jar:2.3.12]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) ~[xwork-core-2.3.12.jar:2.3.12]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191) ~[xwork-core-2.3.12.jar:2.3.12]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) ~[xwork-core-2.3.12.jar:2.3.12]
```

**This works in Tomcat 7.0. But I tried jetty9 and jetty8, none of them work! And in the log, on evidence shows it parsed the tiles file.** You can choose struts version 2.3.14/2.3.12.

Comment: Did you try to move `<listener/>` on the top?

Comment: Strange. Won't a chance to test until next week but I hope to find time (will try to deploy several struts2 tiles-3 projects against jetty) - have tested tomcat and glassfish too and both work as expected.

Comment: “Did you try to move <listener/> on the top? – Lukasz Lenart 21 hours ago” if that, it's a bug of jetty, not a bug of my app. I will give a try!

Comment: To "Lukasz Lenart", even put listener on the top, Still cannot, but my new builds run well in tomcat, but still report "org.apache.tiles.definition.NoSuchDefinitionException: Cannot find definition named 'XXX'" error.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit old, but you might try changing the following  ....

```
<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
```

.... to this:

```
<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="tiles-default">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.DEFINITIONS_CONFIG</param-name>
    <param-value>/common/tiles.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>JspSupportServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.struts2.views.JspSupportServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>

<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
</web-app>

<action name="*LogInAct" method="{1}" class="common.link.OuterLinkAction">
        <result name="welcome" type="tiles">welcome</result>
    </action>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN"
"http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>
<definition name="welcome" extends="preLayout">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="INFINITAS" />
    <put-attribute name="newBody" value="/common/preLayout/preLayout.jsp" />
</definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

Comment: By using above code iam getting no definition found error 500 while running in tomcat 9 and struts 2.5.33 and tile 3